How can I recreate an RAII object without briefly having two?
class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject(fs::path& filename) { ... }
private:
    ...; // [edit] removed poor example with std::vector
};

int main()
{
    MyObject myObject("1_gb_file.dat");

    // Actually I want something else
    myObject = MyObject("2_gb_file.dat");  // <- at one point I have 3gb of file loaded unnecessarily!
}

How can I replace myObject without ever having both allocated at once?
In some ways I'd like the operator=() to be able to happen first, with something a bit like return value optimization to construct the object in-place. A simple way to do what I want is the following, but it means I have a nullable object. I want myObject to be guaranteed always valid but I also want to be able to replace it.
int main()
{
    std::optional<MyObject> myObject("1_gb_file.dat");

    // Better, but not atomic
    myObject.reset();
    myObject = MyObject("2_gb_file.dat");

    // Better, but myObject.reset() still exists and optional holds an extra bool
    myObject.emplace("2_gb_file.dat");
}


Wouldn't something like calling myObject.resize(2<<30); be a better approach?

Good point, but just for this example my object doesn't have a way to resize itself (ignoring its use of std::vector ) and I'm exploring an external resize. For some classes implementing object reuse can get complicated fast.

You will need to add a level of indirection that effectively will trigger a resize. myObject = MyObject_skeleton(2 << 30);. Overload operator= to wick old data and allocate data, in that order. Although this doesn't solve the emplace case, you will need to do .emplace(MyOjbject_skeleton(2 << 30));. All this at least avoid a level of runtime indirection.

If I have to weight on your design, I think you probably need a default constructor and use it strategically to avoid this situation.

Providing default construction to a null state diverges from the RAII goal. So does wrapping with std::optional but it's a bit more explicit.

@jozxyqk "my object doesn't have a way to resize itself" -- then give it one? It seems like any answer you get could get encapsulated in a resize function, and designing a resize function might be easier than trying to work from the assignment perspective.

Consider MyObject("a.txt"). Yes one could write an interface to "resize" it to "b.txt" and reuse the object but it's easier to make mistakes juggling state. E.g. someone adds a member but forgets it needs to be updated in resize()/reopen().

Possibly delete MyObject::operator= and add a MyObject::replace_by(const fs::path& new_path) (with appropriate name replace_by/reopen/assign/...)?

FWIW, there is precedent in the stdlib for replace_by, e.g. std::string::assign

Also, FWIW, you will find yourself working against the language by not having a null state. It's uncommon to do that for a reason. For instance, in an example like here an object with a large state, you can make it noncopyable and more difficult to use, copyable with performance pitfalls, or movable with at least one null (moved-from) state.

Assuming a move assignment operator exists,
MyObject myObject("1_gb_file.dat");

// Actually I want something else
{
    auto tmp = std::move(myObject);
    // destroys myObject
}
myObject = MyObject("2_gb_file.dat");

Shorter version (ty, @o11c):
// destroy myObject
MyObject(std::move(myObject));



16.4.6.15 Moved-from state of library types
Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from (11.4.5.3). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.


3.67 valid but unspecified state
〈library〉 value of an object that is not specified except that the object’s invariants are met and operations on the object behave as specified for its type
Example 1: If an object x of type std::vector<int> is in a valid but unspecified state, x.empty() can be called unconditionally, and x.front() can be called only if x.empty() returns false.

Somewhat related, Jon Kalb makes some good points about how being able to call x.empty() is actually a bad thing for performance, because moving must waste time altering size and capacity. Even worse for std::list using sentinel nodes:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcRHiFH04a4

Note that without actually invoking MyObject(MyObject&&) or MyObject& operator=(MyObject&&), no move actually happens. For example std::ignore = std::move(myObject) does nothing. std::move() is just a cast.

MyObject(std::move(myObject)) is probably best.

RAII is good for automating memory allocation and deallocation, but it's not good for reusing allocations between separate objects.
If you only want one object to exist and you want ensure that there's only one allocation, you don't need RAII and special member functions for that, ordinary member functions will do.
class MyObject {
public:
    MyObject(fs::path& filename) { ... }

    void load(fs::path const& filename) {
        // clear out old data but retain allocation storage,
        // then load data from new filename
    }
private:
};

int main() {
    MyObject myObj("file_1.dat");

    // No extra object
    myObj.load("file_2.dat");

    // No simultaneously-allocated data
    myObj.load("file_3.dat");
}

Easy and readable.

Thanks for your answer. "you don't need RAII" means it's not answering the original question, but it's nice to show that you change the design of an object to encapsulate reuse.

I think what I'm after is something like std::optional but without the optional part. Now that sounds odd, reading it aloud.
template<class T>
class notoptional
{
public:
    template<class... Args>
    notoptional(Args&& ...args) : m_object(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    template<class... Args>
    void emplace(Args&& ...args) noexcept // can't recover from exceptions (see below)
    {
        // Desroy the previous object first
        std::destroy_at(&m_object);

        // Create the new object in-place
        std::construct_at(&m_object, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };

    // access operators
    T& operator*() {return m_object;}
    T const& operator*() const {return m_object;}
    T* operator->() {return &m_object;}
    T const* operator->() const {return &m_object;}
private:
    T m_object;
};

int main()
{
    notoptional<MyObject> myObject("1_gb_file.dat");
    myObject.emplace("2_gb_file.dat");
}

This might be pretty close to std::variant<MyObject> but that has valueless_by_exception and presumably extra storage to support that
*edited to add 'noexcept'

Thinking about the issue of double free if there is an exception, if class T is movable, we could exploit that to at least leave m_object in an internally null state. Then its destructor won't do anything bad.
    // Just for a thought experiment. This is not realy safe.
    template<class... Args>
    void emplace(Args&& ...args) noexcept(!std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<T>)
    {
        // Desroy the previous object first
        if constexpr(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<T>)
        {
            T tmp = std::move(m_object);
            std::destroy_at(&tmp);
        }
        else
            std::destroy_at(&m_object);

        // Create the new object in-place
        std::construct_at(&m_object, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };

Now if an exception happens the destructor won't be called twice. You still end up with an object in a "valid but unspecified state":
void remakeMyObject(notoptional<MyObject>& object)
{
    try {
        object.emplace("2_gb_file.dat");
    } catch (std::bad_alloc& e) {
        // ?
    }
    // caller has no idea that object was just left in an invalid post-move state
}


Note that emplace would very likely cause undefined behavior (by way of double destruction) if T's constructor throws.

Good catch! Related to this. Is there a safer way to do this?

Well, basically, you would need to keep track of whether your notoptional actually holds a valid object (so its destructor may aovid destroying it a second time). At which point, it just becomes std::optional

The trouble with what you are trying to do is that you are breaking the "Strong exception guarantee". If the load of the "2_gb_file.dat" fails you have broken your object (as you destroyed its content before loading). I would say this is supposed to be non atomic operation. You want the reader of the code to understand that you have to destroy the object first then load the new one. Thus this code does not provide the "Strong Exception Guarantee" and thus should be non atomic.

As a result I like option 1 with a comment: myObject.reset();myObject = MyObject("2_gb_file.dat");

Yes - trying to have my cake and eat it too with a not-optional class that inevitably has to transition through a null state when re-creating it. I agree, it shouldn't be done.
